# Avoiding subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, subquery, where-clause

Fellows,
I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, (HUGE SUBQUERY) as HS
FROM TABLE_A JOIN TABLE_B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE (HUGE SUBQUERY) > 0
```

I'd like to avoid repeating the subquery.
Is there any way to rewrite my WHERE as something like

```
WHERE HS > 0
```

Or I must turn my subquery into a join?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid a subquery as a join ?

Comment: Could you post the "huge subquery" as without knowing what it is mean to do a we can only guess :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
WITH cteHS AS (
    SELECT xxx AS Value
        FROM Huge Subquery
)
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, cteHS.Value as HS
    FROM TABLE_A, cteHS
        JOIN TABLE_B ON A.ID = B.ID
    WHERE cteHS.Value > 0
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at With clause :

```
WITH HS AS (Huge subquery)

SELECT A.ID, B.ID, HS
FROM TABLE_A JOIN TABLE_B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE HS  > 0
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT A.ID, B.ID, (HUGE SUBQUERY) as HS
    FROM TABLE_A JOIN TABLE_B ON A.ID = B.ID
)
WHERE HS > 0
```

Comment: SO reputation is very linked to your CPU power :)

Comment: Its probably all the VMs running slowing me down.  I need to get that fixed ASAP